# Selecting Color JavaFx ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, customization

I'm creating a custom ListView with custom ListCells (CellFactory).
this custom cell gets it's design from a fxml file which has a panel in it.
Now this panel has a fixed background color, but i want to change the background of this panel when this cell is selected.

In css i can only change the background of the whole cell and not of the content.

Maybe you have some tipps for me.

EDIT: Here is a minimum Example: the background of the panel should get blue when the cell is selected.

```
 public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane( );

        ListView listview = new ListView<String>(  );
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
            "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4");
        listview.setItems(items);

        listview.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
                                        return new CustomRectCell();
                                    }
                                }
        );

        root.setCenter( listview );
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static class CustomRectCell extends ListCell<String> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            Pane rect = new Pane();
            if (item != null) {

                // This does not work
                if(isSelected())
                    rect.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: Blue;" );
                else
                    rect.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: Red;" );

                setGraphic(rect);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For questions like this a code snippet is absolutely required. How else would we know what "the content" refers to. Asking for "some tipps" is too broad btw, but likely we'll be able to help you with your issue (assuming you [edit] the question and add enough info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomRectCell` won't work for 2 reasons:

1. The selection is independent of the item
2. You never remove the `graphic` so cells that become empty (e.g. if the number of items is reduced), your cells remain filled.

You could override [`updateSelected`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateSelected-boolean-) to assign the background color:

```
static class CustomRectCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private final Pane rect = new Pane();

    {
        // initialize with default background
        rect.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Blue;");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic((empty || item == null) ? null : rect);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelected​(boolean selected) {
        super.updateSelected(selected);
        rect.setStyle(selected ? "-fx-background-color: Red;" : "-fx-background-color: Blue;");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could add a CSS stylesheet to the scene and use it for styling:

```
static class CustomRectCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private final Pane rect = new Pane();

    {
        rect.getStyleClass().add("rect");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic((empty || item == null) ? null : rect);
    }
}
```

CSS stylesheet

```css
.list-cell .rect {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.list-cell:selected .rect {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think the solution with css does work, but the other solution, which i would prefer does not work because wenn implementing the updateSelected method i get the error "method does not overwrite method from superclass". what is wrong there?

Comment: @TobiF That's weird. When I combine your `start` method with the first implementation, it compiles&runs flawlessly. Furthermore the `updateSelected` method is available since JavaFX 2, see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateSelected(boolean)